# Docker and MySQL can't connect

Tags: mysql, linux, node.js, ubuntu, docker

I can't for the life of me figure this out. I feel like I'm really close, but im just not quite there yet. Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Oscar Godson

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs-legacy
RUN apt-get install -y npm
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client

COPY . /src

WORKDIR /src

RUN service mysql start;\
    mysql -u root < /src/bin/demo-data.sql;\
    npm install

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

If i go into interactive mode and go into bash in that `RUN service...` line at the end I can see that mysql is running, the demo data was imported and everything works including starting my Node app with `node index.js`. If I then try to do another `RUN` or the `CMD` you see below it no longer can access MySQL. It's like it stops running.

The error I get `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED` which happens when it's down or the data isn't there. From me playing with it it looks like MySQL isn't running if I try to access it after the `RUN` where I start it.

P.S. The MySQL DB here is purely for development. On production we use AWS RDS, so thats why its using root without any password and importing data that way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `RUN` shouldn't be used for long running processes, however, you can only use one `CMD` option. For some reason it didn't click with me until a friend pointed it out, but I could just make a "installer.sh" script and call that with `CMD`. Now it's not losing the MySQL context. My update Dockerfile looks something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Oscar Godson

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs-legacy
RUN apt-get install -y npm
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client

COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src

RUN cd /src;npm install

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ./bin/installer.sh
```

Installer than has

```
service mysql start
mysql -u root < ./bin/demo-data.sql
node index.js
```